# excel vlookup with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

```
Table 1      Table 2
 A  B        C     D
abc 9       abc   No
hij 0       def   yes
            hij   No

input   output          
abc       9         
def     #N/A            
hij       No
```

I have two tables. If the value exists in column A and the lookup value is greater than 0, then lookup in Table 1, else lookup in Table 2.
I have tried with the formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)),ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)=0),VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)=0),VLOOKUP(A7,$D$2:$E$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE))
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$B$4,2,0),0)>0,VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$B$4,2,0),VLOOKUP(A7,$C$2:$D$4,2,0))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: the output for 'def' is still coming as #N/A. The output should be 'yes'.

Comment: It worked! 
Thanks Scott and apologies for not being specific earlier.